# Email Validation in exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-validation

Currently there are lot of tools which help to verify the email address to reduce the bounce rate.
By email verification I do not mean only syntax. I am talking bout email address being valid and deliverable.
Does exact target have any provision to achieve the same?
Is there any facility in exacttarget where I can load a bulk file containing email address and exacttarget can verify which email is valid or invalid.. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think marketing cloud has an email verification  tool. The list detective feature will validate some common errors in email address and won't send emails to those address. You should be looking at 3rd party like Experian Data Validation.

Comment: Hi, one of our customers is currently working with byteplant. They use a 3 step verification process (syntax, domain, smtp ping) to validate and can be integrated by API. That's probably worth a look, especially as they are also pretty tight on data security.

Comment: I used KickBox...just another 3rd party verification check.  Provides you categories of verified, risky, bounced, and bad.  Pretty slick and fair on price.

Answer (score 3):

Marketing Cloud has a [validateEmail API REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/validateEmail.html) route that can perform 3 validations:

- SyntaxValidator: ensures the format of the email is valid
- MXValidator: ensures the domain exists and readily accepts emails
- ListDetectiveValidator: checks the email address against your Marketing Cloud account's List Detective rules

When you call the validateEmail route, you can choose 1, 2, or all 3 of the validators to check your email address against.

This still won't guard against all possible bounce reasons, though... An individual subscriber's inbox might bounce because it's full, or the receiving server was temporarily down at send time, or a whole host of other reasons.

If you're going to implement the validateEmail check, I'd recommend only doing it at the time you first receive the email address (e.g. when the subscriber submits their email to you through a web form to opt in to email), as it's excessive to run this check on every email address before send time.

Answer (score 0):

check out address endpoint at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm
You can check for the same things list validation does, which isnt perfect but a good start.
You could also build this into an excel macro to validate if needed